# Issues with APACite package undefined control sequence \bibitem

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, errors, citing, apa-style

I get the following errors when I try to cite with `apacite`

```
Undefined control sequence \bibitem{GDP:2012}
You can't use `\relax' after \the \bibitem{GDP:2012}
Citation `GDP:2012' undefined
There were undefined references.
```

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

Some text \cite{GDP:2012}

\bibliography{summative}

\end{document}
```

and here is the BibTeX file

```
@online{GDP:2012,
ALTauthor = {The World Bank},
ALTeditor = {},
title = {GDP Per Capita (Current \$US)},
date = {2012},
url = {http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.PCAP.CD},
}
```

Updated:

```
@misc{GDP:2012,
author = "The World Bank",
editor = {},
title = "GDP Per Capita (Current \$US)",
year = "2012",
url = "http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.PCAP.CD",
}
```

I have ran it twice and the file is in the same directory as my .tex file. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing things.

If you want to use the `plain` bibliography style, load the `natbib` package.  E.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

Some text \cite{GDP:2012}

\bibliography{summative}

\end{document}
```

If you want to use the APA style, then you can do to things: either use `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` with the `natbib` package or go like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}

Some text \cite{GDP:2012}

\bibliography{summative}

\end{document}
```

Your .bib file is fine, but please keep in mind that for the `apacite` package, the entry @online is not supported, nor the "date" characteristic.  However you can use @misc and "year".

Using the second block of code, along with a refs.bib file looking like this:

```
@misc{GDP:2012,
ALTauthor = {The World Bank},
ALTeditor = {},
title = {GDP Per Capita (Current \$US)},
year = {2012},
url = {http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.PCAP.CD},
}
```

creates the following output:

[image]

For more information, please visit both the [apacite package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/apacite/apacite.pdf)  and the [natbib package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf).

Comment: When I run it, I get (n.d) in my bibliography which I am assume means "no date" but I do have date and it is citing the title instead of the author.

Comment: Have you run it a couple of times?  Which package are you using, `natbib` or `apacite`?

Comment: I am using the `apacite` package. I get the bibliography with the name and title and everything except the date.

Comment: please change your "data" entry to "year" in your .bib file and see what happens

Comment: I did that but it's not working. It still says `(n.d)`. Is it working on your end?

Comment: When I run it I have a warning that reads "entry type for GDP:2012 isn't style defined".  What this means is that @online is not defined for the `apacite` package.  Maybe you should try with @misc

Comment: I have updated the code as you said but it still says `(n.d)`. I have posted the new `.bib` file.

Comment: Have you re-run it?  I have a good output.

Comment: I am using TexStudio to run this. I run the bibliography and I get `I couldn't open file name summative.aux` Maybe that is the issue?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with TeXStudio, but I can guarantee you that the code I provided you actually works.

Comment: Yes, I have switched editors and it's working. It's a problem with the IDE. Thanks a lot for your patience and help.

Comment: With `natbib` the style to be used is `plainnat`, not `plain`